# CSS width and overflow

Tags: html, css

If I can't control the width settings for the internal spans (i.e. it is set by some JS) and the combined width is greater than 100%, how can I force it to display them all within the width of the container box without the third span wrapping and displaying underneath the two others.

```css
.box {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.box span {
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <span style="width: 40.0%; background: red;"></span>
   <span style="width: 10.0%; background: green;"></span>
   <span style="width: 50.1%; background: blue;"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex` for the parent element. The flex property will adjusts the excess width into fit with 100%

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

```css
.box {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 3px 0;
  display:flex;
}

.box span {
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <span style="width: 40.0%; background: red;"></span>
   <span style="width: 10.0%; background: green;"></span>
   <span style="width: 50.1%; background: blue;"></span>
</div>
```